# How To Give Consistency To This?

Tags: r

I am trying to build a function that will give me consistent answer of which country has bigger life expectancy change.
When I run

> bigger_change("China", "Bolivia")

it gives me back

> "The country with the bigger change in life expectancy was China (gain=31.88721951), whose life expectancy grew by 7.33797561000001 years more than Bolivia (gain=24.5492439)."

Which looks right but when I switch the two variables and run

> bigger_change("Bolivia", "China")

which gives me back

> "The country with the bigger change in life expectancy was Bolivia (gain=24.5492439), whose life expectancy grew by 7.33797561000001 years more than China (gain=31.88721951)."

which is wrong. The country name stays with its right gain=# but I want the answer to be consistent with the country with bigger change to come first. I know I should fix

```
Bigger_Gain_Country <- x
Smaller_Gain_Country <- y
```

Comment: this answer is unsolvable without your corresponding code

Answer (score 0):

Replace two variables in your code

```
Bigger_Gain_Country = switch(which.max(c(First_Country_Change, Second_Country_Change)), x, y)
Smaller_Gain_Country = switch(which.min(c(First_Country_Change, Second_Country_Change)), x, y)
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!